# Order by association's column works on MySQL but not on Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have those typical `Order`, `LineItem`, `Product`.

An `Order` has many `LineItem`s, and `LineItem` have a `product_id` field.

I am trying to sort `LineItem`s in an `Order` based on a column of the products table, named `code`.

So, this works locally, on a MySQL database, but not in production, where I use PostgreSQL.

```
scope :sort_by_product_id, -> {
  includes(:product)
  .order("products.code asc")
}
```

Error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "products"

LINE 1: ..._id" WHERE "line_items"."order_id" = $1  ORDER BY products...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "line_items"."product_id" WHERE "line_items"."order_id" = $1  ORDER BY products.code asc):
```

I have tried similar with `joins` instead of `includes` but still same error just in production.

Answer (score 1):

```
scope :sort_by_product_id, -> {
  joins(:product)
  .merge(Product.order(code: :asc))
}
```

Comment: First one didn't work, it tries to order by `line_item.code`. But the merge option work nice.

Comment: @pzin Alright, removed the first one, in case of any others got confused. I think you could accept this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
scope :sort_by_product_id, -> do
  includes(:product).order(products: { code: :asc })
end
```

Comment: That gives me another error: `Direction "{:code=>:asc}" is invalid. Valid directions are: [:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]`. Seems that we can't pass a hash there.

Comment: @pzin can you try `.order(code: :asc)` ? which sql it produces ?

Comment: that's trying to order by an unknown `line_items.code` column as the first option suggested by @larrylv.